# Envio Correo Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, email, gmail, cpanel

estoy tratando de enviar correos por mi sistema que ya se encuentra en produccion y que esta en laravel 5.6 (mi web usa https).

y me sale el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi .env esta configurado de la siguiente manera:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=enviosac@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=privado
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

ya cambie el sendmail por smtp, ya cambie el smtp.googlemail.com por smtp.goole.com y nada.

**en mi entorno desarrollo si envia correo.**

he visto que por internet me dice que deshabilite algunos config de mi php.ini , pero esta en Cpanel mi web y no tengo acceso a ello.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:
el error se genera porque estas utilizando `sendmail` como driver
si estas utilizando google no le veo incombeniente en cambiar a `smtp`

**ejemplo:**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=enviosac@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=privado
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: me sale esto `Connection could not be established with host smtp.googlemail.com [Network is unreachable #101]`

Comment: si esta mal el smtp de googe es  `smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: Nada, sigue el mismo error, tu como has implementado tu envio de correo por laravel?